# PyCharm does not find submodules, but console does

Tags: python, pycharm, python-poetry

I cannot properly access submodules in pycharm. Let's say I have

```
import numpy as np
```

And then I tried accessing the testing submodule as `np.testing.assert_all_close()`. The code runs, but pycharm will not recognise the `testing` submodule, or do any kind of autocompletion. If I import like this however, it works:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.testing
```

Then it works as `np.testing...`. This did not happen before, maybe it is an interpreter issue? I am using poetry as environment:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14307-poetry

If I open an iPython console using this same environment, there is no issue, autocomplete works perfectly.

Comment: Make sure you're using the same interpreter/virtual env in PyCharm and console.

Comment: They are the same environment, both pycharm and `sys.executable` give me the same path to the same bin